# function to send email multiple times

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script which sends emails multiple times  with different subject and body each time.

I am trying to move `Send-MailMessage` into a function or something that I could use to reduce the code lines.

```
$Sender = 'jones@example.com'
$text = "<html><body>"
$text += "<p>Welcome</p>"

### A cmdlet that would give recipient email address
$Recipient = (Get-Details -user $user).email

$smtp = "server.example.com"
$subject = "welcome email"

Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml $text -from $Sender -SmtpServer $smtp -Priority high -to $Recipient -Subject $subject

Write-Output "executing commands to capture results"
Write-Output ""
### Few Commands executed in this step
Write-Output "Analyzing results"
### Few commands executed in this step

$newtext = "<html><body>"
$newtext += "Congrats, you are selected"
$newsubject = "results email"

Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml $newtext -from $Sender -SmtpServer $smtp -Priority high -to $Recipient -Subject $subject
```

Comment: You need to format the body anyway, and wrapping a single line of `Send-MailMessage` into a function isn't the way to go.

Comment: I removed _Any suggestions or what I could improve in my script?_ As that can make the question too broad. If you truly want a review of your script consider asking on CodeReview.SE

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function like this:

```
Function Send-Email($text,$subject,$recipient)
{
    Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml $text -From "jones@example.com"
        -SmtpServer "server.example.com" -Priority High -To $recipient -Subject $subject
}
```

You can call it like:

```
Send-Email -text "Hello" -subject "Test" -recipient "test@example.com"
```

You can add or remove arguments depending on what will change though. Assuming the smtp server won't change for example, this isn't needed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to move `Send-MailMessage` into a function or something that I could use to reduce the code lines.

Writing a function for one line *can* be useful if the options are many and never change. However you do have one that changes. There is another PowerShell feature that would work here just as well. [Splatting!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
$emailParameters = @{
    From = $Sender 
    SmtpServer = $smtp 
    Priority = "high" 
    To = $Recipient 
    Subject = $subject
}

Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml $text @emailParameters
# ... other code and stuff
Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml $newtext @emailParameters
```

Now you still only have to make changes in one place and the code is arguably more terse.

Another point is that when you are making multi-line strings all at once, as supposed to building over the course of the script you can always use here strings. You only have two lines but if you code evolves over time it is a good tactic to start early instead of many `$object += "string"` lines

```
$text = @"
<html><body>
<p>Welcome</p>
"@
```

Note that indentation is preserved in the resulting [here-string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx). The `"@` has to appear on its own line with no leading whitespace. Using double quotes means you can still expand variables as well in there.